# DFS View Exception AD Group Based on Folder Permissions

Tags: powershell

Trying to use a script to set a long list of folder to Explicit View in DFS.  I have tried using the DFSUtil.  This is the 3rd step of the process.

Step 1 - Creates New AD Group base on folder name to use specifically in this step.
Step 2 - Added Permission to new AD Group based on current Folder Permissions
Step 3 - This should set the DFS to Explicit View so user are only able to see the folders they have permission to access.

```
    $folderlist = get-childitem -Path "C:\depts"
    $folderlist

    foreach ($folder in $folderlist) {
        $name = $folder.FullName.TrimStart("C:\depts\")
        $ACLLIST = Get-ACL $folder.FullName
        $DFSroot = "\\nsstestdc1\Depts\$name"
        $DFSuser = "ITSTEST\Share-$name-RR"
        $DFSpriv = "R"
        Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\system32\dfsutil.exe" -ArgumentList "property SD grant $DFSroot $DFSuser`:$DFSpriv protect"
}
```

Right now when I run step 3 a screen pops-up and closes so fast that I am unable to see if there are any errors.  I am attempting to run it manually with this code

```
    $DFSroot = "\\nsstestdc1\Depts\Group 1"
    $DFSuser = "ITSTEST\Share-Group 1-RR"
    $DFSpriv = "R"
    dfsutil property SD grant $DFSroot $DFSuser`:$DFSpriv protect
```

The error I believe I am receiving is `Could not complete the command successfully. SYSTEM ERROR - Element not found.`

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is my script check your code with  " ==>  '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dfsutil.exe link add '\\Domain\public\Share1' '\\Server\Share1'
dfsutil.exe Property ACL Control '\\Domain\public\Share1' Protect
dfsutil.exe Property ACL Grant '\\Domain\public\Share1' 'Domain\Domain Admins:F'
dfsutil.exe Property ACL Grant '\\Domain\public\Share1' 'Domain\Server-share1 group Local:R'
```